# How to split a list of two-tuples to separate names

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a list

```
[(1, 1), (2, 1), (3, 2)]
```

I want to split the list so that in the first item `(1, 1)` gets split so that

```
x = 1
y = 1
```

and then it will print a letter, then I want it to iterate through the list. Is there a way of doing this?

Comment: `for x, y in my_list:`?

Answer (score 4):

You can use [sequence unpacking](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#tuples-and-sequences) in python:

```
>>> mytuple = (1,3)
>>> x,y = mytuple
>>> x
1
>>> y
3
```

So you can iterate using:

```
>>> l=[(1,1),(2,1),(3,2)]
>>> for x,y in l:
...   print y,x
...
1 1
1 2
2 3
```

or

```
>>> for (x,y) in l:
...   print y,x
...
1 1
1 2
2 3
```